# Is a domain biholomorphic to the unit ball a Runge domain?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb C^n$ be a bounded domain which is biholomorphic to the unit ball $B^n=\{|z|<1 \mid z\in \mathbb C^n\}$. Can we show $\Omega$ must be a Runge domain? By definition, $\Omega$ is a Runge domain if any analytic function in $\Omega$ can be approximated by polynomials.

Notice that J. Wermer gave a [counterexample](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01420524.pdf) if $\Omega$ is biholomorphic to a bidisk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is NO. Every domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that its image is non-Runge.

See:

Wold, E. F.: A Fatou–Bieberbach domain in $\mathbb{C}^2$ which is not Runge.* Math. Ann. 340 (2008) 775–780

Comment: Dear @LuKa Thaler, what you claimed seems to be false when $n=1$. For example, for every embedding of the open unit disk into $\mathbb{C}$, the image is simply connected hence Runge in $\mathbb{C}$.